# io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, fabric8

Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withMasterUrl("https://c2.eu-de.containers.cloud.ibm.com:78945").build();
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config)) {

```
        client.pods().inNamespace("default").list().getItems().forEach(
                pod -> System.out.println(pod.getMetadata().getName())
        );

    } catch (KubernetesClientException ex) {
        // Handle exception
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://c2.eu-de.containers.cloud.ibm.com:78945/api/v1/namespaces. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:badefault" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope. this errror

Comment: You would need to create `Role` + `RoleBinding`/`ClusterRole` + `ClusterRoleBinding` for your `ServiceAccount` to give it required permissions . You can see an example here: https://github.com/r0haaaan/fabric8-securitycontextconstraints/blob/master/clusterrole.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error looks like your `ServiceAccount` doesn't have the required access to perform that specific operation. You've posted code for listing `Pod` objects but your error is complaining about listing `Namespace` objects.

```
User "system:serviceaccount:badefault" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

You can provide Cluster Admin access to your `ServiceAccount` with this command:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding default-pod --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=<namespace>:badefault
```

If you don't want to give it Cluster Admin access, you can define Custom ClusterRole to restrict which apiGroups and resources you want your `ServiceAccount` to access:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: badefault-cluster-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - "" 
  resources: 
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - create
  - delete
  - deletecollection
  - get
  - list
  - patch
  - update
  - watch
```

You can then define a `ClusterRoleBinding` to bind this `ClusterRole` to your `ServiceAccount` object:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: badefault-cluster-role-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: badefault
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: badefault-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

With this your `ServiceAccount` should be able to access `pods` and `namespace` objects at Cluster Scope.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the ServiceAccount you use `badefault` does not have access to the resource `namespaces`. Please check [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). You need to create the required Role and RoleBinding.