# How to add an ephemeral disk to kubernetes pod?

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes

I need to create an ephemeral disk to get more storage for our jenkins pipeline. This is the try for the pod configuration in the .yaml-File (only one section, since the rest works). What is wrong here? I tried to follow this but must have made a mistake: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/

```
  containers:
    - name: cont
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /extra-disk
        name: extra-disk
  volumes:
    - name: extra-disk
      ephemeral:
        volumeClaimTemplate:
          metadata:
            labels:
              type: cloudbees-ssd
          spec:
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
            storageClassName: "cloudbees-ssd"
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 200Gi
```

Error message: persistentvolumeclaim  "cont-xxx-extra-disk" not found.

Comment: The use of a `volumeClaimTemplate` like this is tagged with `FEATURE STATE: Kubernetes v1.23 [stable]`. Are you running Kubernetes v1.23 or later?

Comment: But note that the storage configuration must be in the `volumes` section, not the `containers` section. Take a closer look at [the example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes).

Comment: @larsks I corrected my post, seems I cropped out too many lines, this is what it looks like with the disk in the volumes section. I am running v1.22, what do I have to change to make it work with that?

Comment: Based on the docs, you would need to upgrade to v1.23. Can you use an `emptyDir` volume instead?

Comment: @larsks I tried it, now it says in the log "Configured service account doesn't have access" similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654569/io-fabric8-kubernetes-client-kubernetesclientexception-forbiddenconfigured-ser. Is this better or worse than "persistent volume claim not found"?

Comment: Can you update your question to show your new configuration?

Comment: @JohnFreeman1212 please open up a new question for the service account issue, since it is not related to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Generic ephemeral volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/#generic-ephemeral-volumes) feature is stable starting in Kubernetes v1.23.

If you want to implement it on any prior version, you can stumble into these kinds of errors.